How to setup Eclipse IDE for Ruby projects under Linux
This question already exists here and here, but I was advised to open a new one.
For me on Ubuntu 24, the text editor fails to show anything, showing the error:
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.eclipse.dltk.ruby.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.dltk.ruby.internal.ui.editor.RubyEditor".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:242)....

(and many hundreds of lines more, similar to this). I have downloaded the All-in-One DLTK SDK - includes binaries and source code of DLTK Core Frameworks, Ruby IDE and TCL IDE for Eclipse Platform 3.3 package from here, and copied and pasted the files from the plugins and feature folders to the ones of my eclipse directory.
When I also install the TLC DLTK from Help->Install new software, the script explorer shows my project folder and I can generate Ruby files etc., but than cannot configure the interpreter any more, getting this error message:
Unable to create the selected preference page.
org/eclipse/dltk/internal/debug/ui/interpreters/InterpreterPreferencePage 

My Ruby interpreter is set to /usr/bin/ruby, which is what comes up for which ruby in my terminal.
Does anybody know how I could repair my setup ? My eclipse is the one for C/C++.


Eclipse 3.3 is 17 years old and no longer supported.

The two links in your question are formatted incorrectly / without the proper footnoting, so it's not currently possible to see the question you referred to or the download source for your Eclipse package.

As Jörg W Mittag pointed out in the comment, eclipse 3.3 is not supported anymore, so the up to date plugin to use is solargraph.


My Ruby interpreter is set to usr/bin/ruby

This should most likely be /usr/bin/ruby, with a leading slash. Try changing that and see if you get better results.
